# MS Office 2010 not working in fedora 22 in Wine

Tags: linux, microsoft-office, fedora, wine

I am new in Linux, Using Fedora 22 beta. I have installed Wine. Then installed ms office standard 2010 package. Everything was okay except the MS PowerPoint.Then thought as we do in windows, I will re-install the Office program. To remove the MS Office 2010, open the wine Add/Remove and select the ms office 10 and select the "Remove" option. But it is show the following message:

> "unable to execute the uninstaller, "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\office Setup Controlled\setup.exe"
> uninstall POWERPOINT /dll OSETUP.DLL. Do you want to remove the unistall entry for this program from registry?"

The message and two options "Yes" or "No."

Then I deleted the entire MS Office file from the .wine folder. But after deleting those file I had seen the MS Office programs in my system tray. Then tried to install the MS Office package again. But it was showing the message that setup has encountered an error. I have tried to install the packages individually but got the same setup error message.

Then I uninstall the Wine and re-install it. But I am unable to install the Office program now.It is the showing that setup encountered an error. Though all the office program are still in my system tray but they are not working. Search net but not find any solution.

Though there is Libre Office program but I have many PPT files which are not opening correctly in Libre Office.

Comment: When you call it Office 10, do you happen to mean, Office 2010?  Because Office 10 wouldn't be Office 2010 it would be I believe 2003.  But reference to a Office14 folder makes that not possible.  Update your question to be specific.

Comment: @ Ramhound ,  i done the change, hope it is better now...

Comment: Do you want specifically office 2010 or an office? I ever worked on this but the version that can work on wine for me is office 2007 https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992&iTestingId=73614&bShowAll=true